# Setting the object to null without passing it as ref

Tags: c#

What's C# language specification for the following behavior. The values of the attributes are retained but the new instance (either null or new object) isn't updated to the actual parameter. It's basically functions as ref except changing the object it points to.

The object in the main function remained intact (not null) but the string attribute has been changed to "Hello World"

```
class Program
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public string str;
    }

    static void MyMethod(MyClass obj)
    {
        obj.str = "Hello World";
        obj = null;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass o = new MyClass();
        o.str = "Hello";
        Console.WriteLine(o.str);
        MyMethod(o);

        Console.WriteLine(o.str); // prints "Hello World"
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? What did you expect vs. what actually happened?

Comment: Does the above actually print "Hello World" (which it shouldn't) or is that what it to do?

Comment: I updated the question, please have a look

Comment: @sarat do the answers below help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In .NET languages, object references are passed by value.

So what does this mean? Conceptually your code is the same as this, with the pointers made explicit:

```
static void MyMethod(MyClass *obj)
{
    obj->str = "Hello World";
    obj = NULL;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyClass *o = new MyClass();
    o->str = "Hello";
    Console.WriteLine(o->str);
    MyMethod(o);

    Console.WriteLine(o->str); // prints "Hello World"
}
```

The parameter passed to `MyMethod` is the value of the pointer `o`, pointing to a `MyClass` instance. You can dereference the pointer to set the value of `str`, but setting the actual pointer value to null doesn't affect the variable in the calling method.

You can pass the reference by reference by doing this:

What's C# language specification for the following behavior. The values of the attributes are retained but the new instance (either null or new object) isn't updated to the actual parameter. It's basically functions as ref except changing the object it points to.

```
class Program
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public string str;
    }

    static void MyMethod(ref MyClass obj)
    {
        obj.str = "Hello World";
        obj = null;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass o = new MyClass();
        o.str = "Hello";
        Console.WriteLine(o.str);
        MyMethod(ref o);

        Console.WriteLine(o.str); // throws NullReferenceException, o is now null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing in the object value by reference. This allows you to change the values of attributes in the object and the changes will be seen in the calling method. However changes to what the variable `obj` refers to will not be seen in the calling method.

If you want the variables reference to be changed throughout you need to pass the reference by reference. To do this you should change the method declaration to:

```
static void MyMethod(ref MyClass obj){...}
```

The documentation for ref can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)